# Process cube without access to the DataSource

Tags: ssas, axapta

I am processing an AX Cube in SSAS Server.

I dont have access to the AX Cube data source and the processing fails.

I am using inherit authentication while processing the cube.Please let me know the solution to the problem.

I need to process the cube in order to bring the data to the cube as it showing no data because it has been backup and restored.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: How does it fail? What are the error messages?

Comment: Error messages is very specific login failure on datasource .I dont have access to the AX Cube but i have restored the backup of the cube in my database(local) but when i process it for data it says login failure due to insufficient permission on the datasource.Is there a way to process the cube?

Answer (score 0):

In order to process cube you have to have access to database it is taking data from.

In other words, in order to process cube SSAS needs to read data from data source. You might need to ask DBA for user to access source database and provide this information in data source settings.

If you inherit authentication settings, SSAS will try to access source database with credentials you have provided to access cube if you do it manually or credentials of task which runs cube processing.

Comment: I have a specific issue as i will not be able to get access on the ERP AX dataSource due to security setting.I want to process the cube in order to fill the data in the cube.I have tried to use inherit authentication but that doesnt help.I am unable to understand the cube until it is processed.

Comment: In order to fill in the cube you have to have access to data source, there is no other way.

Comment: Can we do a type of Reverse engineering...I am trying to achieve the AX Cube Structure into my local database .As i dont have an access on the datasource but i have the cube with me so can it allow me to create a similiar structure in my local without data and thus i would be able to process the cube.Comments invited over the same

Comment: You might try to reverse engineer cube into Visual Studio and take a look at Data source view then. But I am not sure if you can automagically create database structure based on this information.